# How to serve a keras model using Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a keras deep learning model and I have to now process a large dataset over it and calculate the results. This model is already trained, so training is not an issue. I tried exposing my model as a REST service and then calling the same via spark is working fine,but there is a latency factor and for a huge dataset this is a problem. Is there an example someone can quote which I can use as a reference to use my keras model in pyspark and process data by direct python calls instead of REST calls

Comment: You might want to consider RedisDL + spark-redis